# How to neatly space the equals sign when using probabilities?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

When the equals sign is used as part of the probability notation it looks a little odd when typeset in LaTeX, especially when a lot of equals sign occurs in the same line.

E.g.,

```
\[ \Pr(A=a) = \Pr(B=b \mid C=c) \]
```

[image: <Typsesetted equation above>]

The spacing between the equal sign is the same for both the 'equal to' relation and the ones between the random variable (A, B, C) and the constants (a, b, c).

Is ther a way to make the spacing between the latter smaller be than the former, or am I just overthinking this?

Comment: `\[ \Pr(A{=}a) = \Pr(B{=}b \mid C{=}c) \]`

Comment: @gernot I use a similar "hack" whenever expressing values that are offset from a variable e.g. `p{-}1`, `k{+}1` (as opposed to expressing a calculation e.g. `b=a+1`, when I leave the spacing unaffected).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's straightforward to define a macro such as `\newcommand\myeq{\mkern1.5mu{=}\mkern1.5mu}` -- choose the argument of `\mkern` to suit your personal preferences -- and thus to rewrite your equation as

```
 \Pr(A\myeq a)  &= \Pr(B\myeq b \mid C\myeq c)
```

In the TeXbook (p. 174, near bottom of page), though, DEK suggests *not* reducing the whitespace around the `=` symbols but, instead, adding *more whitespace elsewhere* in the full equation via judiciously-placed `\,` directives:

```
 \[ \Pr(\, A=a \,) = \Pr(\, B=b \mid C=c \,) \]
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myeq{\mkern1.5mu{=}\mkern1.5mu}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\Pr(A=a)       &= \Pr(B=b \mid C=c) \\           % original form
\Pr(A\myeq a)  &= \Pr(B\myeq b \mid C\myeq c) \\ % less whitespace around "="
\Pr(\, A=a \,) &= \Pr(\, B=b \mid C=c \,)        % *more* whitespace
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great, I prefer your `\myeq` alternative. Coming to the second part of the question: is it necessary? Is it advisable to make this alteration to the math typesetting when submitting it to a journal (e.g., an Elsevier/IEEE journal)?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac - As long as what you're doing isn't bizarre or odd- looking, the journal will probably not modify your LaTeX code significantly. That said, you may want to ponder the question of how much value-added your notation provides.

Comment: @Mico I wish I could back up your comment, but I've had simple things broken *automatically* like a `nicefrac`-style inline fraction macro, changing `⅓x` into `1/3x` (when I pointed it out we settled on `(1/3)x`).  I understand why, but my point is it gets broken by machine.

Comment: @ChrisH - Thanks for this. I guess that what constitutes "bizarre and odd-looking" can be quite subjective and idiosyncratic. Maybe the `nicefrac` package was just too advanced for the Journal you had to deal with...

Comment: @Mico I rolled my own in a similar style (it's posted here somewhere) . Odd-looking I don't mind -- it's their journal -- but it gave the impression of `1/(3x)`which was wrong.

Comment: @ChrisH -- `1/(3x)` would *definitely* be wrong. Glad you caught the issue in time.

Answer (score 19):

I turn my comment to an answer since I think it is an adequate solution, in particular in this situation, and it is simpler than the other approaches. I also find no flaw in its visual appearance. It also makes sense to me logically, since `A=a` can be viewed as a compound label for an event, not necessarily as an equation. Even if it's an equation, it's just too tiny to be granted the same rights as other equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ \Pr(A{=}a) = \Pr(B{=}b \mid C{=}c) \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: and above all it's a no-brainer :-)

Answer (score 12):

This reduces by half the space around the equals sign in the argument to `\Pr`; it also has the advantage of being able to set the size of the delimiters in an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\PrArg[1]{(}{)}{%
  \renewcommand\given{\Conditional{\delimsize}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`= \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\reducedequals
  \edef\equals{\mathchar\the\mathcode`= }%
  \mathcode`="8000
  #1%
}
\providecommand\given{}
\newcommand{\Conditional}[1]{%
  \nonscript\;#1\vert\nonscript\;\mathopen{}%
}
\renewcommand{\Pr}{\operatorname{Pr}\PrArg}
\newcommand{\reducedequals}{%
  \mskip-.5\thickmuskip
  \equals
  \mskip-.5\thickmuskip
  \nobreak
}

\begin{document}

$\Pr{A=a} = \Pr{B=b \given C=c}$

$\Pr[\big]{A=\frac{1}{2}} = \Pr[\Big]{B=b \given C=\sqrt{\frac{a^{2^n}}{b}}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is not for the manual of best practices, but between treat the equal sing as a very spaced math relation (that is the default equivalent to `\mathrel{=}`) or suppress all this extra space treating the symbol like text (`\mbox{=}` or \text{=} with `amsmat`) or simply grouping it (`{=}`) as gernot pointed, that may be is too drastic, in this case you can simply treat it as an unary or binary operator (`\mathop{=}` or `\mathbin{=}` respectively) although syntactically sound odd. To further but not complete shrinkage, another simple option is add negative spaces in both sides (`\!=\!`). Anyway, it could also a good idea increase a bit the space for the "main equal" sign (with `\,=\,` for instance). My preference is use both `\!=\!` and `\,=\,`. Example:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

%just for the mwe format, no need of preamble code for solutions.
\usepackage{tabto} 
\setlength{\parskip}{.3ex}
\TabPositions{.7\linewidth}

\begin{document}

\( \Pr(A=a) = \Pr(B=b \mid C=c) \) \tab  default\par 
\( \Pr(A\mathrel=a)  = \Pr(B\mathrel=b  \mid C\mathrel=c) \)    \tab  \verb|\mathrel|\par 
\( \Pr(A\mathbin=a)  = \Pr(B\mathbin=b  \mid C\mathbin=c) \)    \tab  \verb|\mathbin|\par
\( \Pr(A\mathop{=}a) = \Pr(B\mathop{=}b \mid C\mathop{=}c) \)   \tab  \verb|\mathop|\par
\( \Pr(A\!=\!a) = \Pr(B\!=\!b \mid C\!=\!c) \)                  \tab  \verb|\!=\!|\par
\( \Pr(A{=}a) = \Pr(B{=}b \mid C{=}c) \)                        \tab  \verb|{=}|\par
$\vdots$\par
\( \Pr(A\!=\!a) \,=\, \Pr(B\!=\!b \mid C\!=\!c) \)      \tab  and  \verb|\,=\,|

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\let\originalPr\Pr
\def\Pr(#1){\originalPr(\mathmakebox{\thickmuskip=.5\thickmuskip #1})}
```

Tweak that `.5` at will.

Comment: You can also work with active characters to not need that `\mathmakebox` that makes things unbreakable in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can re-define the = as binary operator in Pr argument and I recommend to enlarge the `\thickmuskip` for relations (spacing for the outer = etc.), when such "Pr" equations are commonly used in your document.

```
\def\Pr(#1){\mathop{\rm Pr}({\mathcode`=="203D #1})}
\multiply\thickmuskip by3 \divide\thickmuskip by2

$ \Pr(A=a) = \Pr(B=b \mid C=c) $

\bye
```

Comment: This will change the spacing around *all* relation symbols, throughout the document *and* kill its stretchability.

Answer (score 2):

To get the effect of automatically adding {} around every = inside `\Pr`, 
use `\scriptstyle` to eliminate the space around =
and the `relsize` package to scale back up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize, mathtools}
\renewcommand\Pr[1]{\text{P({\larger[2]$\scriptstyle#1$})}}

\begin{document}
\[\text P(A{=}a) = \text P(B{=}b {\mid} C{=}c)\]
\[\Pr{A=a} = \Pr{B=b \mid C=c}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This method will remove space around = as well as <, ≤, +, etc inside `\Pr`. One operator from which you might not want space removed is the conditional probability pipe `\mid`.

To remove space from all operators *except* `\mid`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize, mathtools}
\renewcommand\Pr[1]{\begingroup
    \renewcommand\mid{\;|\;}
    \text{P({\larger[2]$\scriptstyle#1$})}
    \endgroup}

\begin{document}
\[\Pr{A=a} = \Pr{B=b \mid C=c}\]
\[\scriptstyle \Pr{A=a} = \Pr{B=b \mid C=c}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As depicted, this forces space around `\mid` even in `\scriptstyle` environments, where operators typically do not have space.

To remove space from `\mid` in `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle` `\Pr` only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize, mathtools}
\renewcommand\Pr[1]{\begingroup
    \renewcommand\mid{\mathchoice{\;|\;}{\;|\;}{\;|\;}{|}}
    \mathchoice
        {\text{P({\larger[2]$\scriptstyle#1$})}}
        {\text{P({\larger[2]$\scriptstyle#1$})}}
        {\text{P({\larger[4]$\scriptscriptstyle#1$})}}
        {\text{P({\larger[2]$\scriptscriptstyle#1$})}}
    \endgroup}

\begin{document}
\[\Pr{A=a} = \Pr{B=b \mid C=c}\]
\[\scriptstyle \Pr{A=a} = \Pr{B=b \mid C=c}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]