# How to Display Conditional Probability in LyX?

Tags: lyx, conditionals, statistics

I am looking for a way to show `$P(\theta|X)$` but with the proper spacing?

Comment: Use the command `\mid`.

Comment: See [How to neatly space the equals sign when using probabilities?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365353/110998)

Answer (score 3):

The first comment to the question is the right answer:

```
$P(\theta \mid X)$
```